# Laravel - Sending ip to the database on create and updating

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm trying to send the ip address of a user when two events happen

- When an account is created for the user
- Whenever the user requests a page, request to check if the ip is the same or not, if it's not, update

So I know how I can update and also grab the ip address, however, I don't want to copy and paste two pieces of code twice to get the same results.... So what I am asking is, how can I grab the IP once the user is loads the website, store it in a global(?) variable and then use that variable wherever I need it, for example, when the user creates the account, and when a filter checks to see if the ip is the same or not.

So for I tried to add it into my HomeController constructor, but the UserController could not find the variable, and I probably know why. So here's the code.

UserController where I would need it:

```
    public function createUser()
    {

        $newUser = new User;
        $newUser->username = $username;
        // get ip address
        $newUser->ip_address = $userIpAddress;
        $newUser->save();

        if (!Auth::check()) {
            Auth::login($newUser);
        } else {
            return View::make('home');
        }
        return Redirect::action('HomeController@showHome');
    }
```

Filter where I'd check if it's different or not

```
Route::filter('checkUserFilter', function() 
{
    $userIpAddress = Request::getClientIp();

    if (Auth::guest()){
        return Redirect::action('UserController@createUser');
    }  else {

        $user = Auth::user();
        return View::make('home', 
                [   'user'          => $user,
                    'userName'      => $user->username, 
                    'userId'        => $user->id, 
                    'userPass'      => $user->password
                ]
        );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent fires multiple events and you can listen to them.
What you want is to listen to `saving` event which is fired every time model is created or updated (saved to database).
Here is how you can do that.

Eloquent tries to save the model and fires `saving` event. Since you listen to this event you get instance of the model which is being saved at that moment as the function parameter. Now you can set IP address there (or any other attribute)

```
// app/models/User.php

class User extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * Listen for save event
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model)
        {
            $model->ip = \Request::getClientIp();
        });
    }
}
```

Now, the route filter.
Since you set the attribute automaticaly in event listener, it should be enough to call `update` method.

```
Route::filter('checkUserFilter', function() 
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        // ...
    }  else {

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->ip = Request::getClientIp();
        $user->update();

        // ...
    }

});
```

Comment: Aw, I'm still trying to figure out Laravel and I only grasped Controllers and Routers..... So Models will be something else to learn :) I see Laravel comes with an already User.php "model".... Would I stick that code you have wrote inside of that?

Comment: Just stick that code into existing `models/User.php` file, you should be good to go ;) Also, I modified the answer a little, so it's clear now, where the code belongs to

Comment: After looking at this, it feels like my createUser method is wrong. Would there be a better way of doing it?